# Finding the expectation value, variance and normalisation for a piecewise PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the following function $f(x)$, solve the following three problems.

1. Compute $c$ so that $f(x)$ is a valid p.d.f.
2. Compute $E[X]$.
3. Compute $Var[X]$.

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
cx&\text{for $x\in[0,a]$}\\c(2a-x)&\text{for $x\in[a,2a]$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not spoil the question and only provide some hints.

1. You want to find out c such that $f(x)$ is normalized, which means that 
   $$\int_x f(x) dx = 1$$
   $$\int^{a}_{0} cx dx + \int^{2a}_{a} c(2a-x) dx  =1$$
   you can find $c$ by integrating and then solving for $c$ in the above equation.
2. Having found $c$, you have complete knowledge of $f(x)$, use it to solve the following for $E[X]$ 
   $$E[X] = \int_{x}xf(x) dx $$
3. Variance can be expressed as follows which will simplify your task.
   $$Var[X] = E[(X-E[X])^2]$$
   $$\Rightarrow Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$
   $$\Rightarrow Var[X] = \int_{x}x^2f(x) dx - E[X]^2$$

Comment: Thank you. What are the bounds in the integrals to find the expectation? I don't understand how to find them.

Comment: So the bounds will be the same as part 1. , you basically don't have to care about regions where $f(x) = 0$.$$E[X] = \int_{0}^{a}  x f(x) + \int_{a}^{2a} x  f(x) $$. Obviously $f(x)$ is a piecewise function so it will have different values in each bound

Comment: thank you! And how about in the variance' Are the integrals the same?

Comment: Yes indeed, you are right.